# What is the specific Regular Expression of this string, PHP, escaping the quotes

Tags: php, regex

The string quotes included.

```
'test.test.test.test003232'
```

The reg ex I have so far

```
^test.test.test.test[0-99999]$
```

If I removed the quotes in the string, then the regular expression works, but I need to escape the quotes. I tried backslashes

```
^\'test.test.test.test[0-99999]\'$
```

but it didn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is wrong, try this:

```
^\'test\.test\.test\.test([0-9]+)\'$
```

Comment: Don't forget: `/^\'test.test.test.test([0-9]+)\'$/`

Comment: You don't need the parentheses. Also, the dots should be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the `.`, because it will match any character. There is no reason to escape `'`, unless you wrap it in quotes in your PHP, which you didn't provide. `[0-999999]` doesn't make sense, I'll assume you want 6 digits.

Also assuming that you are using `preg_match`, you need delimiters.

It should be:

```
/^'test\.test\.test\.test[0-9]{6}'$/
```

Or inside PHP code:

```
$pattern = "/^'test\.test\.test\.test[0-9]{6}'$/";
```